# filter listbox items with a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListBox` with some `Items`, and a `TextBox`. The text in `TextBox` should match starting characters of `Items` in `ListBox` & should display filtered result. How to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thx to everyone but i made something simpler..
hope that helps ..

Declare a list:

```
       List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

In the main window:

```
      public MainWindow() {
        list.Clear();

        foreach (String str in lb1.Items)
        {
            list.Add(str);
        }
     }
```

In the textchanged event:

```
      public void t1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(t1.Text.Trim()) == false)
        {
            lb1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string str in list)
            {
                if (str.StartsWith(t1.Text.Trim()))

                {
                    lb1.Items.Add(str);
                }
            } 
        }

        else if(t1.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            lb1.Items.Clear();

            foreach (string str in list)
                {
                    lb1.Items.Add(str);
                }
            }                         
        }
```

Comment: Don't so this with booleans ... please.  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(t1.Text.Trim()) == false) ... just put a ! for negation.  if   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(t1.Text.Trim()) {}.  Same with string comparison ...  else if(t1.Text.Trim() == "") .... == string.Emtpy.

Comment: Yes, old thread, but I found it in Google so so will someone else: I **strongly** suggest using the ListBox DataSource for this instead. That is, make a "master List" with every item in it, which is your `list`. Now make a second one, say `FilteredList`, and copy matching items into that. In the editor, bind the ListBox to FilteredList. This is **much** faster than constantly resetting the items - about 15 times in my tests.

Answer (score 2):

I love this example from Josh...

http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/12/searching-for-items-in-a-listbox/#

It's similar approach to the other link - but this one is just brilliant - the shear elegance is good to keep in mind when working with WPF (and how you can get things done in a very simple way).

Comment: thx for the example, I've made it with the TextChanged event.

Comment: np - just spreading `the beauty of the code` :) cheers

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. You shouldn't need to modify the content of the bound items source, just what you see in it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your implementation. Are you following MVVM pattern?

If yes then you can filter your listbox on the set event of your textbox. In the setter you can change contents of your listbox.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText}" />
private string _searchText;
public string SearchText
{
    get { return _searchText; }
    set
    {
        _searchText = value;
        // Change contents of list box.
    }
}
```

And if you are not following MVVM then you need to add a change event handler on textbox. Selecte TextBox and check its events in properties window. There is TextChanged event in it. Add that event. This will give you a function whenever textbox text is changed. And in that function you can implement your logic for filtering listbox.

Comment: Yes I've made it with the TextChanged event. thx