# Filter listbox with textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, filter, textbox, listbox

I've a listbox with a lot of name already added, and now i wanna try to do a simple filter (With the up or low case  doesn't matter, i mean if the user will write on textbox "apple", the listbox show always a result of it) for find the string written on the textbox with the listbox names.
I already tried in this way with cycle for,(to check all the index), but i don't know how to go over the if:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        For counter As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            If InStr(ListBox1.Items(counter).ToString, TextBox1.Text) Then

            End If
            Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean "go over the if"? Are you looking for the `Else` keyword?

Comment: I mean, what should i need to put for show the result of the filter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .NET methods like [`String.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to search sub-strings:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    For counter As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        Dim item = ListBox1.Items(counter).ToString()
        Dim containsText = item.IndexOf(TextBox1.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
        If containsText Then

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If you want to filter this ListBox you could use following LINQ query:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim items = From it In ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object)()
                Where it.ToString().IndexOf(TextBox1.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
    Dim matchingItemList As List(Of Object) = items.ToList()
    ListBox1.BeginUpdate()
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Each item In matchingItemList
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next
    ListBox1.EndUpdate()
End Sub
```

Comment: but how can i show the result of the filter on the listbox ?

Comment: The code work good, but there is a little issues at the end, when i delete the string to search, items on listbox disappear.

Comment: @axel: then check before if the text is empty :)

Comment: It's possible to do an automatic refresh of the list ? like re-loading all the items on the list when textbox is about to be deleted ?

Comment: @Axel: you need to store the orginal filled list somewhere, for example in a field. Or you load it from the datasource again(f.e. a database). The latter has the advantage that you don't see outdated data too long.

Answer (score 0):

It is duplicate of [c# question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627887/filter-listbox-items-with-a-textbox) Here is translated code.

```
Public Sub t1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs)
    If [String].IsNullOrEmpty(t1.Text.Trim()) = False Then
        lb1.Items.Clear()
        For Each str As String In list
            If str.StartsWith(t1.Text.Trim()) Then

                lb1.Items.Add(str)
            End If
        Next

    ElseIf t1.Text.Trim() = "" Then
        lb1.Items.Clear()

        For Each str As String In list
            lb1.Items.Add(str)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```